# hide/show multiple div elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm really new to jQuery and so far I can't figure out what is going on. I'm trying to make a form validation using jquery where I use `CSS visibility` for "tick-mark" and "cross-mark" to be hidden/visible based on what input is being typed on textbox. I want to make this happen for each of my textbox individually but whenever I type something to my 2nd or 3rd textbox the "tick-mark" and "cross-mark" will only show for the 1st textbox. Here are my codes:

```
#tick{
position: relative;
top: 4px;
display: inline-block;
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
background-image: url(Images/tick.jpg);
background-size: 20px 20px;
visibility: hidden; }

#cross{
position: relative;
top: 4px;
display: inline-block;
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
background-image: url(Images/cross.jpg);
background-size: 20px 20px;
visibility: hidden; }
```

CSS codes

```
<b>Full Name : </b><input type="text" name="fullname" id="fname" /><div id="tick"></div<div id="cross"></div><br>
<b>Username : </b><input type="text" name="user" id="user" /><div id="tick"></div><div id="cross"></div><br>
<b>E-mail address : </b><input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="20" /><div id="tick"></div><div id="cross"></div><br>
<b>Postal Code : </b><input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" size="6"><div id="tick"></div><div id="cross"></div>
```

HTML codes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#fname").keyup(function() {
if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/.test($(this).val()) && $(this).val().trim() !== "") {
  //$(this).css("border-color", "#00E600");
  $("#tick").css("visibility", "visible");
  $("#cross").css("visibility", "hidden");
} else {
  //$(this).css("border-color", "red");
  $("#tick").css("visibility", "hidden");
  $("#cross").css("visibility", "visible");
}});
  $("#user").keyup(function() {
if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/.test($(this).val()) && $(this).val().trim() !== "") {
 $("#tick").css("visibility", "visible");
  $("#cross").css("visibility", "hidden");
} else {
  $("#tick").css("visibility", "hidden");
  $("#cross").css("visibility", "visible");
}});
  $("#email").keyup(function() {
if (/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/.test($(this).val()) && $(this).val().trim() !== "") {
  $("#tick").css("visibility", "visible");
  $("#cross").css("visibility", "hidden");
} else {
  $("#tick").css("visibility", "hidden");
  $("#cross").css("visibility", "visible");
}});
  $("#postcode").keyup(function() {
if (/^(?:\+\d{1,3}|0\d{1,3}|00\d{1,2})?(?:\s?\(\d+\))?(?:[-\/\s.]|\d)+$/.test($(this).val()) && $(this).val().trim() !== "") {
  $("#tick").css("visibility", "visible");
  $("#cross").css("visibility", "hidden");
} else {
  $("#tick").css("visibility", "hidden");
  $("#cross").css("visibility", "visible");
}});
 })
```

jQuery codes

Any idea how can I solve it? Any idea will be helpful! Tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I've found a solution. This is working for me. I just assigned different IDs for different textboxes but used the same two class `.tick` and `.cross` for all textboxes. This made my problem solved.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#fname").keyup(function() {
if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/.test($(this).val()) && $(this).val().trim() !== "") {
$("#t1").css("visibility", "visible");
$("#c1").css("visibility", "hidden");
} else {
$("#t1").css("visibility", "hidden");
$("#c1").css("visibility", "visible");
}});
})
```

jQuery Code

```
<b>Full Name : </b><input type="text" name="fullname" id="fname" /><div id="t1" class="tick"></div<div id="c1" class="cross"></div><br>
```

HTML code

Tnx to all for providing a light to my mind.

Answer (score 2):

DOM element IDs should be unique.  Use classes instead. For example,

```
$(".tick").css("visibility", "hidden");
$(".cross").css("visibility", "visible");
```

All elements with the class `tick` will be hidden and `cross` will be visible.

ADDITIONS:

To show ticks or crosses for the fullname field only, I suggest

```
<input type="text" name="fullname" id="fname" /><div id="tick_fname"></div<div id="cross_fname">
```

with jQuery,

```
$("#fname").keyup(function() {
    if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/.test($(this).val()) && $(this).val().trim() !== "") {
    $("#tick_fname").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#cross_fname").css("visibility", "hidden");
} else {
    $("#tick_fname").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $("#cross_fname").css("visibility", "visible");
}});
```

You can repeat this for the other input fields.  Did you consider `.show()` and `.hide()` to toggle visibility?

Comment: it's not working. now the tick/cross shows in all if I type any one of the textbox. I want one tick/cross one at a time.

Comment: Yes of course since now it affects all elements with the same class.  Please see my edited answer.

Comment: What u did is using unique IDs for each textbox just what others mentioned. But is there any way I can use only those two CSS classes? And yes I did tried `.show()` or `.hide()` but couldn't solve with them.

Answer (score 1):

You're using IDs, which mean the elements that are assigned with an ID should be unique. In your case, they're not. Try adding a unique identifier to each box and then it should work.

Comment: I know that trick earlier but I don't want to use 10 IDs for 10 textbox.

Answer (score 0):

**I misunderstood your question. If you want to select specific items, they need to have some attribute, id, class or something to make each #tick unique.**

As you are using the '#' symbol in your JQuery selector, you are only getting one element as a result. It is because id's should be unique.

Having said that, if instead of using:

```
$("#tick").css("visibility", "visible");
```

You use:

```
$('[id="tick"]').css("visibility", "visible");
```

the JQuery selection will return all the elements with an id similar to "tick", and your .css() will be applied to all the elements with that id.

Here you have a working example:
http://jsbin.com/dinejahe/1/edit?html,js,output